# React component does not re-render when updating state from Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to rerender a component in React.

The setup:

1. I am using React Context to fetch some data from a Firestore database. So the fetching is Async.
2. My component is then fetching the data using: `static contextType = MyContext` and accessing via `this.context`
3. I store this context data on the components state to try to trigger a rerender whenever this data is changed.
4. I pass the data to a child component where it renders a list based on this data.

The problem:

1. I manage to update the state and even when debugging I can see my state updating to the correct data BUT the component does not rerender either the childcomponent or the list.
2. The expected list shows as soon as I click anything on the page so my guess is that the data is trapped in some kind of middle stage.

What I've tried:

1. I tried using the componentDidUpdate to make a check if the context is different than the current state and trigger a function that sets the state (I have even tried with setState function directly after the check) => Still state updates but no rerender is triggered (I can see the new data on state)
2. I tried using the getDerivedStateFromProps on the child component to do a check if the Props have changed and also tried storing the props in the child components own state => Still same result as before.

I am not sure what else to try, I thought that React triggers a rerender everytime state chages but probably I am doing something really wrong.

Here is my parent:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import styles from './artistdropdown.module.css';

import { returnCollection } from '../../utils/Firebase.js';
import MyContext from '../../utils/MyContext.js';
import ArtistSelected from './ArtistSelected.js';
import ArtistsList from './ArtistsList';

export class ArtistDropdown extends Component {
    static contextType = MyContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            artists: [],
            currentArtist: {
                id: null,
                name: null
            }
        };
        this.fetchArtist = (aId, artists) => {
            const state = {
                id: null,
                name: null,
            };
            artists && artists.forEach((a) => {
                if (a.id === aId) {
                    state = {
                        ...state,
                        id: a.id,
                        name: a.name,
                    }
                }
            })
            return state;
        }
        this.loadToState = (state) => {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                ...state,
            })
        }
        this.click = (id) => {
            this.context.handleArtistSelection(id);
            this.props.handleBandDropdown();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const aId = this.context.state.user.last_artist;
        const artists = this.context.state.user.artists;
        const currentArtist = this.fetchArtist(aId, artists);
        const state = {
            artists: artists,
            currentArtist: currentArtist,
        }
        this.loadToState(state);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
        if (this.state.artists !== this.context.state.user.artists) {
            const aId = this.context.state.user.last_artist;
            const artists = this.context.state.user.artists;
            const currentArtist = this.fetchArtist(aId, artists);
            const state = {
                artists: artists,
                currentArtist: currentArtist,
            }
            this.loadToState(state);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const bandDropdown = this.props.bandDropdown;
        return (
            <>
                <ArtistSelected
                    currentBand={this.state.currentArtist.name}
                    handleDropdown={this.props.handleBandDropdown}
                    expanded={bandDropdown}
                />
                <ul className={bandDropdown ? styles.band_options + ' ' + styles.expanded : styles.band_options}>
                    <ArtistsList artists={this.state.artists} />
                </ul>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ArtistDropdown
```

and here is my child:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import MyContext from '../../utils/MyContext.js';
import ArtistItem from './ArtistItem.js';

export class ArtistsList extends Component {
    static contextType = MyContext;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            artists: [],
        };
        this.loadToState = (state) => {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                ...state,
            }, () => { console.log(this.state) })
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const artists = this.props.artists;
        const state = {
            artists: artists,
        }
        this.loadToState(state);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
        if (state.artists !== this.state.artists) {
            this.loadToState(state);
        }
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        if (props.artists !== state.artists) {
            return {
                artists: props.artists,
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    render() {
        // const artistList = this.state.artists;
        const artistList = this.state.artists;
        const list = artistList && artistList.map((a) => {
            return (<ArtistItem key={a.id} onClick={() => this.click(a.id)} name={a.name} />)
        })
        return (
            <>
                {list}
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ArtistsList
```